I define a subcomponent with an input box in another component. Why does the subcomponent lose focus when inputting?
While developing, I extracted part of the content from the parent component into a child component, which is naturally more complex than the code in the example. When I try to enter text in the input box, it loses focus after each input. So I have written similar code to illustrate the issue. Could you please help me resolve this?
import { useState } from 'react';

function App () {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  const Input = () => (<input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



Can you please explain more what you mean and what is the output you want

This sounds like an issue with the events bound to the input box (or possibly the DOM in general), not specifically a React component problem. As such, there's not enough information in the question to help you solve the issue

I have described the problem in detail.

What you did is a declaration of a component within a component:
const Input = () => (<input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />)

Jack Herrington talks about it in his video "3 React Mistakes, 1 App Killer"
More in depth explanation: the reason is the mechanism of reconciliation. React compares current shape of Virtual DOM to previous shape. Among other things, the identity of each element is compared, i. e. the reference to the function which creates the element. You create a new reference to Input on each render of App and this is why Input is dismounted and remounted on each text change. I don't understand why you did that, just do this:
function App () {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={text} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}


Thanks for your answer. The code is a demo, the child component in my project is more complex than it.

The point still stands; if it's too big to inline, extract it to another file and import it.

Such a new way to write I've never thought of it before.
It's definitely because rerendered, but how it worked maybe need to read react source code.
Maybe you could try the following code?
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  const Input = useCallback(
    ({ t, onChange }) => <input value={t} onChange={onChange} />,
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input t={text} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}


Thanks. But I know how to solve it, but I want to know why.
